# skip pre-commit hook conditionally from within commit-msg hook

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a precommit hook that ensures topic branch is always rebased with devel before any commits. However, sometimes in the middle of my work I'd like to commit my unfinished work as opposed to stashing it just in case and reset before resuming. The commit message has to be exactly the same for such work-save commits, say 'worksave commit'. I'd like commit-msg hook to check for such condition and skip precommit hooks if it's a work-save commit. precommit hook listens to environment variable '`override_hooks`' at all times so I tried to alter that within commit-msg but that didn't work. I understand that I can set override_hooks manually but I was hoping I won't have to do that every time. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `prepare-commit-msg` hook is run *after* the `pre-commit` hook, so that won't work.

You would be better off setting an alias :

```
# call 'git commits with
# -n to skip all pre-commit hooks
# -m msg to provide the commit message from the command line
git config alias.worksave 'commit -n -m "works save commit"'

# you can now type :
git worksave
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice for a workaround. However, since it would be specific to command line commits I used this idea to simply handle the branch comparison in the commit-msg hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `commit-msg` hook which is invoked by `pre-commit` instead. My hook uses too many internals to include here but the idea is to read `$1` (the commit message file) and perform the checks accordingly to ascertain an exit code and/or message.

My current `commit-msg` that implements this has a number of self-contained dependencies and is written in `R` but I'll paste it here in case it can be of any help.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript

## check if commit msg has 'resetme' or 'worksave' (a save-work commit)
## if not, check and ensure 'devel' branch is not ahead

.stop <- function(msg) {
    stop('\n\n', msg, '\n\n', call. = FALSE)
}

## source utilities from GitHub
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ##
source('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajabadi/Altools/master/R/get_package_version.R')
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ##
source('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajabadi/Altools/master/R/bump_up_version.R')

## get commit message
commit_message <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
commit_message <- paste0(readLines(commit_message), collapse = ' ')

## ascertain if it was a worksave commit
its_a_save_work_commit <- grepl('^resetme', tolower(commit_message)) | grepl('^worksave', tolower(commit_message))


## exit with 1 if devel is ahead of topic and it's not a worksave commit
## exit with 0 otherwise
currBranch <- current_branch()
if (isFALSE(its_a_save_work_commit)) {
    ## remind to rebase devel for topic branches if necessary
    if (!any(currBranch %in% c('master', 'devel'))) {
        devel_is_ahead <- length(system(sprintf('git log %s..devel', currBranch), intern = TRUE)) > 0
        if (devel_is_ahead) {
            .stop('devel is ahead by some changes, rebase or start the commit message with either "worksave" or "resetme"\n')
        }
}
TRUE
}
```